# Cake php with Ext js through display data in grid Problem

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, extjs, integration

I create cakephp with extjs grid view .

For that i create,

1)one movie_controller controller file in which i write

```
function index() {
        $this->recursive = 0;                                      
        $this->set('movies', $this->Movie->find("all"));

    }
```

2)second create index.ctp file in view/movies/index.ctp

```
 <?php echo  '{"rows":'.$javascript->Object($movies).'}'; ?>
```

3)then in js file i call this index.ctp file

not getting data in grid.
when debugging in firebug it's display this array

{"rows":[{"Movie":{"id":"1","date_":"1970-01-01","notes":"Note13455-","asset_id":"1","maint_picture":"","maint_condition1":"Poor","maint_condition2":" New","maint_condition3":"Excellent","maint_condition4":"Good"}},{"Movie":{"id":"2","date_":"2009-03-20","notes":"Note2","asset_id":"1","maint_picture":null,"maint_condition1":"Excellent","maint_condition2":"Excellent","maint_condition3":"New","maint_condition4":"Poor"}}]}

==>In this json file how can i remove Movie array which is display in start all record.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo  '{"rows":'.$javascript->Object($movies['Movie']).'}'; ?>
```

Comment: if i write this in index.ctp file <?php echo '{"rows":'.$javascript->Object($movies['Movie']).'}'; ?> it's given error that Notice (8): Undefined index: Movie [APP\views\movies\index.ctp, line 2]{"rows":null} means array return null values . Please help..

Answer (score 0):

if want to remove first array remove from array we have to one by one array print in grid.
 its done.

```
<?php
$output='{"rows":[';
$total=$ta=count($movies);
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
{
$t=$i+1;
  if($t==$total)
  {
    $output.=$javascript->Object($movies[$i]['Movie']);
  }
  else
  {
    $output.=$javascript->Object($movies[$i]['Movie']).',';
  }
}
$output.=']}';

echo $output;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting closer. Try doing all the work with your `$movies` variable in the controller (remember the MVC pattern! Don't break it!).

You can do so by doing something like...

```
// in your controller
$data = null;
$movies = $this->Movie->find('all');

foreach ($movies as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value['Movie'] as $k => $v {
        $data['rows'][$key][$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Then turn that into a json object.

Basically I think it's not loading the data because your json looks like this

{"rows":[{"Movie":{"id":"1","date_":"1970-01-01","notes":"Note13455-","asset_id":"1","maint_picture":"","maint_condition1":"Poor","maint_condition2":" New","maint_condition3":"Excellent","maint_condition4":"Good"}},{"Movie":{"id":"2","date_":"2009-03-20","notes":"Note2","asset_id":"1","maint_picture":null,"maint_condition1":"Excellent","maint_condition2":"Excellent","maint_condition3":"New","maint_condition4":"Poor"}}]}

it should look like this

{
"rows": [{
    "id":"1",
    "date_":"1970-01-01",
    "notes":"Note13455-",
    "asset_id":"1",
    "maint_picture":"",
    "maint_condition1":"Poor",
    "maint_condition2":" New",
    "maint_condition3":"Excellent",
    "maint_condition4":"Good"
}, {
    "id":"2",
    "date_":"2009-03-20",
    "notes":"Note2",
    "asset_id":"1",
    "maint_picture":null,
    "maint_condition1":"Excellent",
    "maint_condition2":"Excellent",
    "maint_condition3":"New",
    "maint_condition4":"Poor"
}
]}

You want to remove the `"Movies": {..object..}` part, so it's just an array of objects like `{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3}` etc.

Make sure you have rows set as your root in your JsonReader!!

```
var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root: 'rows'
});
```